# using spring cache read only, how set spring cache redis read only

Tags: spring-cache

when I use spring cache with **redis**, I use it in two app, the one read and write,the other is only read,how can I config?

I try do like this, but it does not work!

```
@Cacheable(value = "books", key = "#isbn", condition = "false")
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 7):

You have misunderstood the purpose of the `@Cacheable` annotation's "`condition`" attribute. Per the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache-annotations-cacheable-condition)...

> If true, the method is cached - if not, it behaves as if the method is
>   not cached, that is executed every since time no matter what values
>   are in the cache or what arguments are used.

The `condition` attribute just determines whether the cache (e.g. Redis) is consulted first, before executing the (potentially expensive) method.  If `condition` evaluates to **false**, then the method will always be executed and the result subsequently cached.

In the read-only app, I am assuming you want the cache consulted first, if the value is not in the cache, then execute the method, however, DO NOT cache the result.  Is this correct?

If so, then you only need specify the `unless` attribute instead of the `condition` attribute like so...

```
@Cacheable(value="books", key="#isbn", unless="true")
void someBookMutatingOperation(String isbn, ...) { .. }
```

If, however, you want to avoid the cacheable method invocation in the read-only (version of the) app altogether and just consult the cache regardless of whether a value actually exists in the cache or not, then your problem is quite a bit more complex/difficult.

Spring's Cache Abstraction operates on the premise that if a value is not in the cache then it will return null to indicate a cache miss, which is then followed by a subsequent method invocation.  Only when a cache returns a value for the specified key(s) will the method invocation be avoided.

Without a custom extension (perhaps using (additional) AOP interceptors) there is no way to avoid the OOTB behavior.

I will not elaborate on this later technique unless your use case requires it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks!   "If, however, you want to avoid the cacheable method invocation in the read-only"  is correct.   i used CacheManager later.  it can solve. but it's not a nice solution

Comment: Cache.ValueWrapper extendInfo = cacheManager.getCache("words").get(word);

Comment: Referencing the CacheManager in your code directly is NOT what I mean at all regarding the later UC.

Comment: IMHO it should say `unless = "true"` here.

Comment: @Matthias - yes you are correct, see the follow up answer below.  I will correct my original/first answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Tonney Bing

First of all, my apologies for misguiding you on my previous answer...

> If condition evaluates to **false**, then the method will always be
>   executed **and the result subsequently cached**.

The last part is NOT true.  In fact, the `condition` attribute **does** prevent the `@Cacheable` method result from being cached.  But, neither the `condition` nor the `unless` attribute prevent the `@Cacheable` service method from being invoked.

Also, my code example above was not correct.  The `unless` attribute needs to be set to **true** to prevent caching of the `@Cacheable` method result.

After re-reading [this section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache-annotations-cacheable-condition) in the Spring Reference Guide, I came to realize my mistake and wrote an [example test class](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/ConditionalCachingTest.java) to verify Spring's "conditional" caching behavior.

So...

With respect to your business use case, the way I understand it based on your original question and subsequently, your response to my previous answer, you have a `@Cacheable` service method that needs to be suppressed of invocation in the read-only app regardless of whether the value is in the cache or not!  In other words, the value should always be retrieved from the cache and the `@Cacheable` service method should **NOT** be invoked in read-only mode.

Now to avoid polluting your application code with *Spring* infrastructure component references, and specifically, with a *Spring* `CacheManager`, this is a good example of a "cross-cutting concern" (since multiple, mutating-based application service operations may exist) and therefore, can be handled appropriately using AOP.

I have coded such an example satisfying your requirements [here](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/UseCacheExclusivelyInReadOnlyModeCachingTest.java).

This is a self-contained test class.  The key characteristics of this test class include...

1. The use of external configuration (by way of the `app.mode.read-only` System property) to determine if the app is in read-only mode.
2. The use of AOP and a custom Aspect to control whether the subsequent invocation of the Joint Point (i.e. the @Cacheable service method) is allowed (no, in a read-only context).  In addition, I appropriately set the order in which the Advice (namely, the `@Cacheable` based advice along with the `handleReadOnlyMode` advice in the `UseCacheExclusivelyInReadOnlyModeAspect` Aspect) should fire based on  precedence.
3. Take note of the `@Cacheable` annotation on the service method...

   ```
   @Cacheable(value = "Factorials", unless = "T(java.lang.System).getProperty('app.mode.read-only', 'false')")
   public Long factorial(long number) { .. }
   ```

You can see the intended behavior with the `System.err` output statements in the test class.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

@John Blum
thanks! happy new year.
your answer inspired me, I have read a part of the spring cache source code. the CacheInterceptor class. the CacheAspectSupport class.

```java
private Object execute(CacheOperationInvoker invoker, CacheOperationContexts contexts) {
        // Process any early evictions
        processCacheEvicts(contexts.get(CacheEvictOperation.class), true, ExpressionEvaluator.NO_RESULT);

        // Check if we have a cached item matching the conditions
        Cache.ValueWrapper cacheHit = findCachedItem(contexts.get(CacheableOperation.class));

        // Collect puts from any @Cacheable miss, if no cached item is found
        List<CachePutRequest> cachePutRequests = new LinkedList<CachePutRequest>();
        if (cacheHit == null) {
            collectPutRequests(contexts.get(CacheableOperation.class), ExpressionEvaluator.NO_RESULT, cachePutRequests);
        }

        Cache.ValueWrapper result = null;

        // If there are no put requests, just use the cache hit
        if (cachePutRequests.isEmpty() && !hasCachePut(contexts)) {
            result = cacheHit;
        }

        // Invoke the method if don't have a cache hit
        if (result == null) {
            result = new SimpleValueWrapper(invokeOperation(invoker));
        }

        // Collect any explicit @CachePuts
        collectPutRequests(contexts.get(CachePutOperation.class), result.get(), cachePutRequests);

        // Process any collected put requests, either from @CachePut or a @Cacheable miss
        for (CachePutRequest cachePutRequest : cachePutRequests) {
            cachePutRequest.apply(result.get());
        }

        // Process any late evictions
        processCacheEvicts(contexts.get(CacheEvictOperation.class), false, result.get());

        return result.get();
    }
```

I think should prevent the cachePutRequest execute. if no cache be hit, to invoke the method body of @Cacheable and don't cached the result.  use unless will prevent the method invoke. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, use "`unless`".  Though, the value should be set to *true*.  I corrected my original/first answer above.  Cheers.